# ViewEventActivity.class is not recognised

Tags: android, wear-os

my code source is https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

in this sample code the second part NotificationCompat is working like a charm..but I have this code in MainActivity.class and it is giving an error that **"ViewEventActivity.class is not recognised"**

Now what is this ViewEventActivity.class,where to add it and how to implement this

***Code snippet::***

```
   int notificationId = 001;
    // Build intent for notification content
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ViewEventActivity.class);
    viewIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_ID, eventId);
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
            .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
            .setContentText(eventLocation)
            .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

    // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "ViewEventActivity.class is not recognized"

`ViewEventActivity` is not related to any API's classes. so you need to create your own class which you want to open on notification click with any name instead of `ViewEventActivity` like other class .

So create `ViewEventActivity` class in your application by extending `Activity`

Also add `ViewEventActivity` class as Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <activity
     android:name=".ViewEventActivity"
      ...  
  />
```

Comment: Thank you @ρяσѕρєя K
what type of content do we need to add in this class

Comment: @PrathibhaKirthi: any information which you want to show . for testing just add any normal layout with TextView

Comment: Great help ρяσѕρєя K...give me a moment..lemme implement your suggestion

Comment: @PrathibhaKirthi: like you are currently sending `eventId` with intent. for testing get it using `getIntent()` method in `ViewEventActivity` Activity and show in TextView as String. but actual use is depend own project or task requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Repalce

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ViewEventActivity.class);
```

with

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent();
```

Thats the sample code for launching the Activity on click of Notification.Its not related to Android API.if you want to launch any Activity on click then repalce that `Activity` with `ViewEventActivity.class` otherwise ignore it

Comment: Thank you @kalyan...this did a trick...i did **Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);**